# Dynamically select the number of text inputs from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the number of text inputs based on a selection in a drop down list. For example, if the user chooses the number 4 in the drop down list, then there will be 4x4 number of text inputs. The values in the text inputs will be mapped into the equivalent 2d array. I am able to save into an 2d array but can't generate inputs dynamically.

What I've currently got is i can create a row of fields on a button press.

```
            <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://cachefile.net/scripts/jquery/1.2.3/jquery-1.2.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // start a counter for new row IDs
        // by setting it to the number
        // of existing rows
        var newRowNum = 0;

        // bind a click event to the "Add" link
        $('#addnew').click(function(){
            // increment the counter
            newRowNum += 1;

            // get the entire "Add" row --
            // "this" refers to the clicked element
            // and "parent" moves the selection up
            // to the parent node in the DOM
            var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

            // copy the entire row from the DOM
            // with "clone"
            var newRow = addRow.clone();

            // set the values of the inputs
            // in the "Add" row to empty strings
            $('input', addRow).val('');

            // replace the HTML for the "Add" link 
            // with the new row number
            $('td:first-child', newRow).html(newRowNum);

            // insert a remove link in the last cell
            $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">Remove<\/a>');

            // loop through the inputs in the new row
            // and update the ID and name attributes
            $('input', newRow).each(function(i){
                var newID = newRowNum + '_' + i;
                $(this).attr('id',newID).attr('name',newID);
            });

            // insert the new row into the table
            // "before" the Add row
            addRow.before(newRow);

            // add the remove function to the new row
            $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                return false;               
            });

            // prevent the default click
            return false;
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table id="tabdata">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>Cell 1</th>
                    <th>Cell 2</th>
                    <th>Cell 3</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a id="addnew" href="">Add</a></td>
                    <td><input id="n0_1" name="n0_1" type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input id="n0_2" name="n0_2" type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input id="n0_3" name="n0_3" type="text" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input id="go" name="go" type="submit" value=" Save " />
    </form>
```

The script i've created to save into an array is

```
        var array = new Array();

        function insert(val){
            array[[0],[array.length]]=val;
        }

        function insert2(val){
            array[[1],[array.length]]=val;
        }

        function show() {
            var string="<b>All Element of the Array :</b><br>";
            for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                string =string+array[i][0]+"<br>";
                string =string+array[0][i]+"<br>";
            }
            if(array.length > 0)
                document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = string;
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Array from Input</h2>
    <form name="form1">
        <table width="407">
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right"><b>Name</b>
                <td width="9"><b>&nbsp;:</b>
                <td width="224">
                <input type="integer" name="name"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">


                <td width="154" align="right"><b>Name2</b>
                <td width="9"><b>&nbsp;:</b>
                <td width="224">
                <input type="integer" name="name2"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">
                <input type="button" Value="Add Into Array" 
                       onclick="insert(this.form.name.value), insert2(this.form.name2.value);"/>

                        <input type="button" Value="alert" onclick="alert(array[1][0])"/>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have not made the two scripts compatible yet. One problem at a time.

Comment: A jsFiddle showing what these two scripts actually do in the context of a page would be very useful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YHLP3/

If you add a value in name and name 2. click add and then alert, it will show you the value in array[1][0], this shows that i can add into an 2d array.

The next part shows i can add rows of text input, but i dont know how to use a drop down list to select the number of rows and column and then add into the array.